# How to work with nested arrays in alpinejs?

Tags: alpine.js

i have been having trouble iterating through nested arrays with x-for and alpinejs.  I have something like matches:

```
25: {person1: {name: 'Pete', nickname: 'Petey'}, person2: {name: 'John', nickname: Johnny'}}
26: {person1: {…}, person2: {…}}
27: {person1: {…}, person2: {…}}
28: {person1: {…}, person2: {…}}
29: {person1: {…}, person2: {…}}
30: {person1: {…}, person2: {…}}
31: {person1: {…}, person2: {…}}
32: {person1: {…}, person2: {…}}
80: {person1: {…}, person2: {…}}
```

So say we have a Matches, each Match has 2 People and each person has a bunch of information.  I was hoping I could do something like:

```
<template x-for="(match, matchIndex) in matches">
```

But this errors straight away with "items.forEach is not a function" -  I am able to have some success if i use Object.values(matches), but then I lose the ability to grab the correct index for the match.

What is the right way to iterate through this such that I can access all of the information?

***UPDATE*** Updating to provide more detailed information -

matches is defined in appState and is updated as the result of a fetch. matches looks like:

```
25: {person1: {name: 'Pete', nickname: 'Petey'}, person2: {name: 'John', nickname: Johnny'}}
26: {person1: {…}, person2: {…}}
27: {person1: {…}, person2: {…}}
28: {person1: {…}, person2: {…}}
29: {person1: {…}, person2: {…}}
30: {person1: {…}, person2: {…}}
31: {person1: {…}, person2: {…}}
32: {person1: {…}, person2: {…}}
80: {person1: {…}, person2: {…}}
```

Ok so i tried it 3 ways.

1.

```
<div x-data="appState" x-init="findMatches();">

<template x-for="(match,matchIndex) in matches" :key="matchIndex">
    <span x-text="match.person1.name"></span>
</template>

</div>
```

My expecation here was that each entry in matches would iterate through as a match.  Then i would be able to access match.person1.name and match.person2.name.

Allthough, when i run this i get the following error in the cosole - "Uncaught TypeError: items.forEach is not a function"

Thinking that perhaps there was an error iterating through the matches array like this i attempted the following.

2. I attempt to do the following

```
<div x-data="appState" x-init="findMatches();">

<template x-for="(match,matchIndex) in Object.values(matches)" :key="matchIndex">
<div>
    <span x-text="matchIndex"></span>
    <span x-text="match.person1.name"></span>
</div>
</template>

</div>
```

This works to give me the person1 name, however the indexes are rewritten useing Object.values and i need the correct indexes from matches.  Plus i would also like to know how to do this properly.  So i tried a different way which might give me the indexes that i need.

3. I attempt the following:

```
<div x-data="appState" x-init="findMatches();">
            <template x-for="(match, matchIndex) in Object.entries(matches)" :key="matchIndex">
                <div>
                    <span x-text="matchIndex"></span>
                    <template x-for="(actualMatch,actualMatchIndex) in match" :key="actualMatchIndex">
                        <span x-text="actualMatch"></span>
                    </template>

                </div>
            </template>

</div>
```

matchIndex comes out with rewritten indexes. actualMatch returns what seems to be an array something like 25: Proxy(Object) .... and i have trouble accessing the properties.  If i instead change

`<span x-text="actualMatch"></span>  to   <span x-text="actualMatch.person1"></span>`

i get a proxy(Object) with my person1 details, however i cant seem to access the properties.  Ie.  If i do actualMatch.person1.name - i receive a message like:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"
```

Any assistance with how to do this properly would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you and apologies if my initial question wasn't sufficiently details.

***UPDATE #2***

Requested information regarding the findMatches and the appState.

I've been trying to figure it out, but im still struggling. It seems like for some reason the matches isnt available for the x-for.  But... If i console log this.matches from the function (in the script) it returns the correct data. I have an almost identical function working elsewhere.  I just don't quite understand.

```
<div x-data="appState" x-init="findMatches(34);">

            <template x-for="(match,matchIndex) in matches" :key="matchIndex">

                <span x-text="console.log(match)"></span>
            </template>

</div>



<script>
const appState = {
            matches: [],
            async findMatches(eventID){
                try{
                    let response = await fetch('/admin/getMatches/' + eventID);
                    let data = await response.json();

                    this.matches = data;
                    console.log('shouldve written to data by now');

                } catch (itsTheErrorObject){
                    console.log('Something went wrong');
                }
            }
}
</script>
```

The console.log from the span doesn't log anything in the above example, and i get the "Uncaught TypeError: items.forEach is not a function" for the x-for.

Strangest thing is, if i change "in matches" to "in Object.entries(matches)" or "in Object.values(matches)" it console.logs as expected.

***UPDATE 3***
Request actual dataset being returned from fetch. See below:

```
{
    "25": {
      "person1": {
        "id": 49,
        "name": "John",
        "nickname": "Johnny"
      },
      "person2": {
        "id": 50,
        "name": "Pete",
        "nickname": "Petey"
      }
    },
    "26": {
      "person1": {
        "id": 51,
        "name": "Svetlana",
        "nickname": "Svetty"
      },
      "person2": {
        "id": 52,
        "name": "Alexander",
        "nickname": "Alex"
      }
    }
  }
```

Fingers crossed I've made a blunder here.

Comment: Could you share a little bit more of the component? Where does the error occur exactly? Where do you use the `items` variable in the template?

Comment: Sorry - phone posted mid post. The error occurs when I call the template x-for - I don't have any vars called items - I assumed (maybe wrongly) this was part of the error message. The error doesn't occur for example if I changes "in matches" to "in Object.values(matches)"

Comment: I mean you should include the whole error message and the component where it occurs so I can reproduce the problem. Alpine.js can loop through nested arrays without problem, so obviously there's an error in your code. But if share only a very simple single line then it's impossible to solve the problem. Don't try to guess where is the problem and include only that part in your question. Rather include a minimal, but complete example that reproduces the problem. You'll get answer much quicker if people can see the whole picture.

Comment: Apologies @Dauros - Have updated the question with more information.  Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: Thanks! Your first version is working for me without any issue. So there's something probably with `appState` or `findMatches()` methods. Could you share them as well? Or maybe the returned data has some problems E.g. the "Johnny" string is missing a quotation mark in the example.

Comment: Thanks mate, adding in another update to the question for more info, too long for here.

Comment: Since you are doing only a standard `fetch()`, now I'm starting to suspect the response from the backend. Could you share a raw response from the backend that raises the error?

Comment: Thanks @Dauros I really appreciate your assistance.  I've updated the information in the question in update 3.

Comment: Ok, now I see what is the problem: Alpine.js expects that `matches` is an array, but it is a single large object. We need to transform it, before using it with `x-for`. When you mention `matchIndex` you want to have the loop index from 0 to `length-1`, or the returned object index like 25 and 26 in your example?

Comment: I'm trying to get the object index like 25 and 26.  (When I used Object.values(matches) I was able to get a result but without the object indexes which I am trying to achieve. 

Is there a simple way to transform the object into an array suitable for x-for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) returns an array of key-value pairs of the object. The `(match,matchIndex)` indexing is almost good, but it [tells](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/for#accessing-indexes) Alpine.js to populate the key-value pair to the first variable `match`, then it populates the second variable with the loop index. However you want to grab the key-value pairs returned from `Object.entries()`. The correct syntax for that is to use square brackets: `[matchIndex, match] in Object.entries(matches)`:

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
<script>
const matches = {
    "25": {
      "person1": {
        "id": 49,
        "name": "John",
        "nickname": "Johnny"
      },
      "person2": {
        "id": 50,
        "name": "Pete",
        "nickname": "Petey"
      }
    },
    "26": {
      "person1": {
        "id": 51,
        "name": "Svetlana",
        "nickname": "Svetty"
      },
      "person2": {
        "id": 52,
        "name": "Alexander",
        "nickname": "Alex"
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<div x-data>
  <template x-for="[matchIndex, match] in Object.entries(matches)" :key="matchIndex">
      <div>
          <span x-text="`Match #${matchIndex}:`"></span>
          <span x-text="`${match.person1.name} (#${match.person1.id}) vs. ${match.person2.name} (#${match.person2.id})`"></span>
      </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

If you prefer you can apply `Object.entries()` right after you call the API so you can remove it from the template code.

Comment: Hey Mate, that worked great!  Thanks again for all of your assistance!